# Using winutils and HBaseMiniCluster to unit test code

Tags: scala, maven, unit-testing, hbase, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to spawn a HbaseMinicluster by following this tutorial:

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-test-hbase-applications-using-popular-tools/

The only difference is that I am doing it in scala.

I have set up winutils as well (as my error is the same as [Hadoop on Windows. YARN fails to start with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964216/hadoop-on-windows-yarn-fails-to-start-with-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror)).

Below is my pom file:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.vikas</groupId>
  <artifactId>TestHBase</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
  <description>My wonderfull scala app</description>
  <inceptionYear>2015</inceptionYear>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>My License</name>
      <url>http://....</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>cloudera</id>
      <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>apache-repo</id>
      <name>Apache Repository</name>
      <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>cloudera-repo-releases</id>
      <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/repo/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>


  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalatest_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.6</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <!-- make sure wrong scala version is not pulled in -->
          <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.specs</groupId>
      <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase-testing-util</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0-cdh5.9.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0-cdh5.9.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0-cdh5.9.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0-cdh5.9.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0-cdh5.9.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    -->
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals> 
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <useFile>false</useFile>
          <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
          <!-- If you have classpath issue like NoDefClassError,... -->
          <!-- useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar -->
          <includes>
            <include>**/Test*.*</include>
            <include>**/*Suite.*</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>target/surefire-report</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>during-tests</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Below is my test case:

```
import com.vikas.TestHBaseGetSpark
import org.junit.Assert._
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{Get, HTableInterface, Put, Result}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test

object TestMyHBaseIntegration{
  val utility:HBaseTestingUtility=new HBaseTestingUtility
}

class TestMyHBaseIntegration {

  val test: Array[Byte] = "TestTable".getBytes
  val CF: Array[Byte] = "CF".getBytes
  val CQ1: Array[Byte] = "CQ-1".getBytes
  val CQ2: Array[Byte] = "CQ-2".getBytes

  @Before
  def setup(): Unit = {
    //utility = new HBaseTestingUtility
    TestMyHBaseIntegration.utility.startMiniCluster
  }

  import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
  import org.junit.Test

  @Test
   def testFetch(): Unit = {
    val table = TestMyHBaseIntegration.utility.createTable(test, CF)
    val objPut:Put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("123"))
    objPut.addColumn(CF, CQ1, Bytes.toBytes("abc"))
    objPut.addColumn(CF, CQ2, Bytes.toBytes("xyz"))
    table.put(objPut)
    assertEquals("TestTable", table.getTableName)
  }
}
```

When I fire mvn test from cli, I get the following error:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 13.094 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestMyHBaseIntegration
testFetch(TestMyHBaseIntegration)  Time elapsed: 13.093 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:609)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canWrite(FileUtil.java:999)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyzeStorage(Storage.java:540)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.analyzeStorage(Storage.java:500)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverStorageDirs(FSImage.java:319)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:1097)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:779)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:676)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:844)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:823)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1547)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.createNameNode(MiniDFSCluster.java:1114)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.createNameNodesAndSetConf(MiniDFSCluster.java:985)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.initMiniDFSCluster(MiniDFSCluster.java:814)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.<init>(MiniDFSCluster.java:745)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniDFSCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:585)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:987)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:868)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:862)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:806)
        at TestMyHBaseIntegration.setup(TestMyHBaseIntegration.scala:25)
```

If someone here has faced a similar issue, can you please help me in identifying what am I doing wrong here?

PS: I am using java 8.

The following message also shows up after running mvn test:

```
7/09/19 18:31:40 INFO hbase.HBaseCommonTestingUtility: Starting up minicluster with 1 master(s) and 1 regionserver(s) and 1 datanode(s)
17/09/19 18:31:40 INFO hbase.HBaseCommonTestingUtility: Created new mini-cluster data directory: D:\scala_dev\TestHBase\target\test-data\642abce9-f187-4f95-a9c3-50e3913228e6\dfscluster_2b336f9c-ba28-4fcd-bd93-bdb954b52fa5, deleteOnExit=true
17/09/19 18:31:40 INFO hbase.HBaseCommonTestingUtility: Setting test.cache.data to D:/scala_dev/TestHBase/target/test-data/642abce9-f187-4f95-a9c3-50e3913228e6/cache_data in system properties and HBase conf
17/09/19 18:31:40 INFO hbase.HBaseCommonTestingUtility: Setting hadoop.tmp.dir to D:/scala_dev/TestHBase/target/test-data/642abce9-f187-4f95-a9c3-50e3913228e6/hadoop_tmp in system properties and HBase conf
17/09/19 18:31:40 INFO hbase.HBaseCommonTestingUtility: Setting hadoop.log.dir to D:/scala_dev/TestHBase/target/test-data/642abce9-f187-4f95-a9c3-50e3913228e6/hadoop_logs in system properties and HBase conf
17/09/19 18:31:40 INFO hbase.HBaseCommonTestingUtility: Setting mapreduce.cluster.local.dir to D:/scala_dev/TestHBase/target/test-data/642abce9-f187-4f95-a9c3-50e3913228e6/mapred_local in system properties and HBase conf
17/09/19 18:31:40 INFO hbase.HBaseCommonTestingUtility: Setting mapreduce.cluster.temp.dir to D:/scala_dev/TestHBase/target/test-data/642abce9-f187-4f95-a9c3-50e3913228e6/mapred_temp in system properties and HBase conf
17/09/19 18:31:40 INFO hbase.HBaseCommonTestingUtility: read short circuit is OFF
17/09/19 18:31:40 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old issue, but in case someone still needs to solve it....

I had that same situation and I started from the very beginning: Installing hadoop (2.8.5 in my case), setting HADOOP_HOME (in my case c:\hadoop), adding the \bin to the path (%HADOOP_HOME%\bin)), and then I [downloaded winutils for that same Hadoop version](https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils) and put all those files on c:\hadoop\bin (overwriting the original ones).
At that point, you should be able to run winutils (open cmd, run winutils command. It should show the help). In case it's unable to find MSVCR100.dll, you need to install the [Visual C++ Runtime libraries](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/confirmation.aspx?id=26999) . Only if it doesn't work, you should try to copy hadoop.dll to windows\system32.

I used [this link as a reference](https://kontext.tech/column/hadoop/377/latest-hadoop-321-installation-on-windows-10-step-by-step-guide) (just to understand the process until step 6):
I hope this will could help others to reduce the time I required.