# py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o49.csv

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to pyspark. I'm running pyspark in the local machine. I'm trying write to CSV file from pyspark data frame. So I wrote the following code

dataframe.write.mode('append').csv(outputPath)

But I'm getting an error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\org\spark\weblog\SparkWebLogsAnalysis.py", line 71, in <module>
    weblog_sessionIds.write.mode('append').csv(outputPath)
  File "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 1372, in csv
    self._jwrite.csv(path)
  File "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o49.csv.
: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createDirectoryWithMode(NativeIO.java:560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkOneDirWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:534)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:586)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:559)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.mkdirs(ChecksumFileSystem.java:705)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.setupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:354)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.setupJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
```

Can you suggest me to rectify this error?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30964410/2129801) can help

Comment: I have already configs hadoop.dll in env var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem got resolve by deleting hadoop.dll file from winutils folder and using lower version of Spark