# how do you configure snappy with hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, snappy

I am trying to configure hbase with snappy. I installed snappy and hadoop native libraries:

```
 ls /usr/local/lib

adp.pm              libprotobuf-lite.la         libprotobuf.a          libprotobuf.so.8.0.0  libprotoc.so.8      libsnappy.so.1.2.0
libhadoop.a         libprotobuf-lite.so         libprotobuf.la         libprotoc.a           libprotoc.so.8.0.0  pkgconfig
libhadoop.so        libprotobuf-lite.so.10      libprotobuf.so         libprotoc.la          libsnappy.a
libhadoop.so.1.0.0  libprotobuf-lite.so.10.0.0  libprotobuf.so.10      libprotoc.so          libsnappy.la
libjvm.so           libprotobuf-lite.so.8       libprotobuf.so.10.0.0  libprotoc.so.10       libsnappy.so
libprotobuf-lite.a  libprotobuf-lite.so.8.0.0   libprotobuf.so.8       libprotoc.so.10.0.0   libsnappy.so.1
```

when I try to go to hbase shell, I keep getting this error:

2015-06-23 08:03:46,542 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

Also unable to created tables with SNAPPY on HBASE. Can somone help me to configure snappy with hbase?

```
create 'testsnap', {NAME=>'cf', COMPRESSION=>'SNAPPY'}
```

returns these errors:

```
ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy()Z
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.sanityCheckTableDescriptor(HMaster.java:1336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createTable(HMaster.java:1269)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices.createTable(MasterRpcServices.java:398)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java:42436)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2031)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy()Z
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CompressionTest.testCompression(CompressionTest.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.checkCompression(HMaster.java:1462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.checkCompression(HMaster.java:1455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.sanityCheckTableDescriptor(HMaster.java:1334)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy()Z
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.checkNativeCodeLoaded(SnappyCodec.java:63)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.getCompressorType(SnappyCodec.java:132)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getCompressor(CodecPool.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getCompressor(CodecPool.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.compress.Compression$Algorithm.getCompressor(Compression.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CompressionTest.testCompression(CompressionTest.java:96)
        ... 11 more
```

Comment: "Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform" has got nothing to do with your snappy. That's warning and can easily be igonored. Can you explain how you are trying to apply snappy..?

Comment: After installing snappy i just do this..                                                                >  create 'testsnap', {NAME=>'cf', COMPRESSION=>'SNAPPY'}

Comment: @ruby, I've update the post with the errors.

Comment: @ruby, I can create tables within hbase with COMPRESSION=>"NONE', snappy not working.

Comment: Unsatisfied errors comes when native libraries are not able to properly load. Recheck your installation of snappy..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150417/hadoop-mapreduce-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-apache-hadoop-util-nativec

Comment: @ruby, I placed export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib in hbase-env.sh file and worked.

Comment: good luck with hbasing..:)

Comment: You dont really need that as /usr/local/lib is default. I am guessing you did not do a `ldconfig` after installation.

Comment: @FUD, I did perform ldconfig