# Hadoop Compression ERROR: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy()Z

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, snappy

When I'm running Apache Kylin on Hadoop, I met the following error related to Hadoop MapReduce:

```
2019-03-20 08:06:00,193 ERROR [main] org.apache.kylin.engine.mr.KylinMapper: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy()Z     
at org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader.buildSupportsSnappy(Native Method)     
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.checkNativeCodeLoaded(SnappyCodec.java:63)     
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec.getCompressorType(SnappyCodec.java:136)     
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getCompressor(CodecPool.java:150)     
at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CodecPool.getCompressor(CodecPool.java:168)     
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.init(SequenceFile.java:1304)     
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1192)     
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$BlockCompressWriter.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1552)     
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:289)     
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.createWriter(SequenceFile.java:542)     
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat.getSequenceWriter(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:64) 
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(SequenceFileOutputFormat.java:75)     
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.LazyOutputFormat$LazyRecordWriter.write(LazyOutputFormat.java:113)     
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.MultipleOutputs.write(MultipleOutputs.java:468)
```

I guess the reason is that Hadoop cannot find the libsnappy.so* native library. I have searched solution online. Following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150417/hadoop-mapreduce-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-apache-hadoop-util-nativec), I have already added the following properties in corresponding xml files and restarted services:

```
# For HDFS core-site.xml
<property>
  <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
  <value>
    org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
  </value>
</property>
# For MapReduce2 mapred-site.xml
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.admin.user.env</name>
  <value>LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/hdp/${hdp.version}/hadoop/lib/native</value>
</propert
<property> 
  <name>mapreduce.map.output.compress</name>  
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.map.output.compress.codec</name>  
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress</name>
  <value>true</value> 
</property> 
<property> 
  <name>mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec</value> 
</property>
```

However, it didn't work. So I dig into the log of YARN. I found that in the launch_container.sh part, it has the following command:

```
export PWD="/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1553049994285_0013/container_e04_1553049994285_0013_01_000005"
# ...omit other commands
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$PWD"
```

I think this command is wrong since instead of $PWD, the true path of to libsnappy.so* is.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/hdp/${hdp.version}/hadoop/lib/native
```

Also as you can see, I have already set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to the true path in the mapred-site.xml file. Why does yarn still use $PWD?

Besides, I added one log message which is shown as follows. This ensures that the env LD_LIBRARY_PATH is really set mistakenly. So how can I solve this problem?

```
2019-03-20 08:06:00,044 INFO [main] org.apache.kylin.engine.mr.KylinMapper: linyanwen[from map]: /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/root/appcache/application_1553049994285_0039/container_e04_1553049994285_0039_01_000005
```

Thanks!